# Extract integer from a random array

Tags: c

I have as input integer,cahr,symbol random array. I want to extract only integers from that array.

For example: input is `[@56gY68#$&*+7j^78gu5];`

output is `56 68 7 78 5`

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
void main()
{
  char arr[10];
  int arr1[10],i;
  clrscr();
  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    scanf("%s",arr[i]);
  }
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
      if(isdigit(arr[i])){
          arr1[i]=arr[i];
      }
  }
  for(i=0;i<10;i++){
      printf("%d",arr1[i]);
  }
  getch();
}
```

The code fails to extract an integer. What do I need to change?

Comment: `scanf("%s",arr[i]);` --> `scanf("%c",&arr[i]);` , `arr1[i]=arr[i];` --> `arr1[i]=arr[i]-'0';` , `int arr1[10],i;` --> `int arr1[10]={0},i;`. If this doesn't work as expected, you need to clarify your question and add more details on what you want as the output (with an example to clarify things)

Answer (score 3):

The code shown here  invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). The problems in your code:

1. `scanf()` requires a *pointer* type argument to store the scanned value.
2. `%s` is for *strings*, `%c` is for `char`.
3. for `%c`, the `\n` is *not* ignored. So, you've to use it like `" %c"` to avoid the trailing *newline*.

However, I don't see any logic to "extract **only one** integer from a random array". You may need to check your logic once again.

Notes:

- The recommended signature of `main()` is `int main(void)`.
- always initalize all your local variables.

Comment: Actually it should be "all integer". Sir i changed the title.

Comment: @Sutanu then, there's another question, how do you tell _which_ input was `int`? I mean, in that case, `isdigit` will fail and `arr1[i]` won't be assigned. You __must__ initalize `arr1`, at least.